# Expression or idiom for overacting when assuming a blame

Tags: expressions, idioms

In Romanian we have an expression that translates word-by-word as "pouring ashes onto one's head" -- used when someone exaggerates in assuming the blame for something that went wrong, e.g., by repeatedly stating it:

"I'm such an idiot, I shouldn't have left the door open... how could I be so stupid? What was I thinking?"

"Alright, stop *pouring ashes onto your head* and let's focus on what we can do to fix this!"

What would be the closest English equivalent?

Comment: Carried to extreme lengths, someone might (literally or figuratively)['fall on their sword](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fall_on_one%27s_sword)'. The Japanese call the literal action [seppuku](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seppuku).

Answer (score 6):

> ### Beat (oneself) up
>
> To continually criticize or question oneself, usually about something that one cannot change.
> —[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+yourself+up)

In the context of your example, it's normally used with "...about it." For example...

> So you spilled the ashes. Don't *beat yourself up about it*.

Comment: So you spilled the beans, in English. :)

Answer (score 1):

to **self-flagellate** [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-flagellation)

*extreme* criticism of oneself

As in:

> "Alright, stop with the **self flagellation** and let's focus on what
>   we can do to fix this!"

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar phrase in England and it is 'Donning sackcloth and ashes' from an old religious custom of wearing a rough hessian garment and covering oneself in Ashes to give penance to God for a grievous sin

Answer (score 0):

The way you have worded the example I would think that you could say: "Don't make a mountain out of a mole hill."

Example: "I'm such an idiot, I shouldn't have left the door open... how could I be so stupid? What was I thinking?"

"Alright, stop (or 'don't make') making a mountain out of a molehill, just focus on what we can do to fix this!"